# Restriction maps in definition of a subsheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

The following definition is given in Hartshorne's book:

> **Definition:** A *subsheaf* of a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf $\mathcal{F'}$ such that for every open set $U \subseteq X$, $\mathcal{F'}(U)$ is a subgroup of $\mathcal{F}(U)$ and the restriction maps of the sheaf $\mathcal{F'}$ are induced by those of $\mathcal{F}$.

Now when Hartshorne says

> *"the restriction maps of the sheaf $\mathcal{F'}$ are induced by those of $\mathcal{F}$"*

I'm sure he means that if we have open sets $V \subseteq U$ of $X$, then the restriction map for $\mathcal{F'}$ $$\rho'_{UV} : \mathcal{F'}(U) \to \mathcal{F'}(V)$$ is just the restriction of the restriction map for $\mathcal{F}$ $$\rho_{UV} : \mathcal{F}(U) \to \mathcal{F}(V)$$ to the subgroup $\mathcal{F'}(U)$. But for $\rho'_{UV}$ to even be well-defined $\mathcal{F'}(V)$ needs to be defined in such a way that we have $\rho_{UV}(\mathcal{F'}(U)) \subseteq \mathcal{F'}(V)$.

*So the question is*: Is this condition also implicit to the definition of a subsheaf?

---

If you think categorially in terms of what properties a subobject has in the category of sheaves of abelian groups I think that the answer would be yes to the above.

Comment: Yes, that's what a subsheaf means.